# Android timezone discrepancy

Tags: java, android, timezone

I wrote a simple java program

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()); // printing Asia/Calcutta
```

Same line of code in Android file:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()); //printing America/New_York
```

My default time zone is Asia/Calcutta, why is this happening? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**In Java** `TimeZone.getDefault()` is initialized that way:

1. Look up the system property "**user.timezone**" (this is always a good work-around to start your application with this property set to "Asia/Kolkata").
2. If not present then look at "**user.country**" and "java.home" and use native method for accessing platform zone information (so you should really check your android-OS-configuration for timezone).
3. If still not present then **fall back to GMT**.

UPDATE:

For **Android** (which is not really Java) you can also check [this other SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930726/where-does-android-take-default-timezone-from) where an answer mentions the system property `System.getProperty("persist.sys.timezone");`. You can try to print out this property for you and follow given links there.

Comment: user.timezone and user.country how to see these properties.

Comment: @ParitoshAhuja Look at `System.getProperty("user.timezone");` (normally yielding `null` unless you have explicitly started your application with this property), but your main task should be checking your OS-settings for timezone.

Comment: I don't want to hard code the value, i want to fetch the timezone specific to that location and then use it.

Comment: @ParitoshAhuja Keep in mind that in many important cases one given location has more than one timezone (examples: US, Russia etc.).

Answer (score -1):

You can Always use :

```
TimeZone tz = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
```

Comment: I tried this but the output was same as that of Timezone.getDefault().